# How to reorder list items on window resize using jQuery/media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to do some responsive fix - Currently I have a list somthing like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>666</li>
  <li>555</li>
  <li>444</li>
  <li>333</li>
  <li>222</li>
  <li>111</li>
</ul>
```

If the screen size is less then 767px, I like it to change the order like this :

```
<ul>
  <li>111</li>
  <li>222</li>
  <li>333</li>
  <li>444</li>
  <li>555</li>
  <li>666</li>
</ul>
```

And fix them back to current state if the size increases.

I understand that this cannot be done through CSS media query, I need your help fixing it through jQuery.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Without knowing the purpose and layout of that list, I'd go with flexbox and doing flex-direction: row-reverse; with mediaqueries. Does that sound feasible?

Comment: First of all you have invalid html. You must close your `li` elements. `</li>`

Comment: size means `Height` or `Width` ?

Comment: Size means - I am concerned about Width.

Comment: @laaposto - not true here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20550925

Comment: @Julix No, you are wrong! I didn't say that `<li>` elements must have ending tags but the format OP had before the edit is invalid. Are you telling me that this markup
 `<ul>
  <li>666<li>
  <li>555<li>
</ul>`

is valid?

Comment: @laaposto - Seems I should have checked the edit history to know what you meant - obviously that's not valid. I just took you literally by your word "must close your li", which isn't accurate, but given the weird markup I get why you said that. It's simpler than "must not open more <li> than you need - either close using slash (</li>) or take out the trailing <li>"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reverse the elements in `ul` elements like this:

```
$("ul").append(function(){
    return $(this).children().detach().toArray().reverse();
});
```

Combined with `window.resize`:

```
var resizeTimeout, sortedReverse = false;
$(window).resize(function () {
    // window.resize fires too rapidly for our liking
    // use clear-set timeout approach
    if (resizeTimeout) {
        window.clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
    }
    resizeTimeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        // sortedReverse flag is used to ensure that
        // we do not reverse the list unnecessarily
        if ((windowWidth < 767 && !sortedReverse) || (windowWidth >= 767 && sortedReverse)) {
            $("ul").append(function () {
                return $(this).children().detach().toArray().reverse();
            });
            sortedReverse = !sortedReverse;
        }
    }, 100);
}).trigger("resize");
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/d3wyg/)

Comment: **+1** for spending your time to make a clean solution :)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to reverse the order of the children of a specific element, you could do tis:

```
$.fn.reverseChildren = function() {
  return this.each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.children().each(function(){ $this.prepend(this) });
  });
};

$("ul").reverseChildren();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/xKvj3/)

Reference: [Reverse order of a set of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942733/reverse-order-of-a-set-of-elements)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
        $('ul').append( $.makeArray( $('ul li') ).reverse() );
    }
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/LsYzv/

Answer (score 1):

First of all: I do not like it when people say "this cannot be done"
Of course it can be done with PURE CSS.

`display:flex` is helping you in so many ways!

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
  <li>666</li>
  <li>555</li>
  <li>444</li>
  <li>333</li>
  <li>222</li>
  <li>111</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
ul{
    display:flex;
    list-style: none;
    flex-direction:column;
}
@media(max-width: 766px){
    ul{
        flex-direction:column-reverse;
    }
}
```

Here the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8zyo3pa/) and also the embeded Code:

```css
ul{
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 list-style: none;
}
@media(max-width: 766px){
 ul{
  flex-direction:column-reverse;
 }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>666</li>
  <li>555</li>
  <li>444</li>
  <li>333</li>
  <li>222</li>
  <li>111</li>
</ul>
```

### Dont forget: nothing is better then pure CSS which is working flawless!!!