# Reverse order of divs in pure plain JavaScript no CSS

Tags: javascript

I can't find a post on here that is not jQuery based I need a plain JavaScript example and please don't suggest anything CSS solution related. I am aware that there is CSS methods to do things similar to this but for personal reasons I need a JavaScript solution for this instead.

Ok I need to make all the .x class names div's to be in reverse order so it will look like this

```
D
C
B
A
```

At default it looks like this

```
A
B
C
D
```

and I want the scroll box of the scroll bar on page load to start at the bottom with the reverse order of the .x div's like this photo shop image I created.

[image: Targeted outcome]

Here is my code currently

```js
/*???*/
```

```css
#a{
  background-color: gold;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}

#b{
  background-color: orange;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.x{
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
 position: relative;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id='a'>
  <div id='b'>
    
    <div class='x'>
      <h1>A</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->
    <div class='x'>
      <h1>B</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->

    <div class='x'>
      <h1>C</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->

    <div class='x'>
      <h1>D</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->
    
  </div><!--</b>-->
</div><!--</a>-->
```

Comment: This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942733/reverse-order-of-a-set-of-elements) and has a solution based in plain Javascript that should work for you by user [Ayman Abdel-Rahman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333614/ayman-abdel-rahman).

Comment: Thanks for your reply I saw that post earlier and I could not get it to work with my code if you know how you can get this to work with my code can you give an example by that post if you know how to get it to work if you don't know how that's ok I failed at getting that method to work with my code.

Comment: I have provided an answer to your specific question.

Comment: Check my answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Pure javascript solution to reverse the divs

```
var divElems = document.getElementsByClassName('x');
var divB = document.getElementById('b');

var output = [];
for(var i =divElems.length - 1; i >= 0;i--){
  output.push(divElems[i]);
}

b.innerHTML = '';
output.forEach(function(eachDiv){
    b.appendChild(eachDiv);
});
```

Working demo - https://jsfiddle.net/71kpLqne/

Comment: Thanks front_end_dev for your reply the reverse ordering works great but how can I set the scroll box at the bottom on page load?

Answer (score 0):

You can firstly get all the divs using 
`document.querySelectorAll('.x');`

Then reverse this order using `.reverse()`. Then you can turn this array of DOM elements into a string of 'string' DOM elements using `.reduce()`:

```js
const divs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.x')];
const new_order = divs.reverse().reduce((acc, elem) => acc+elem.outerHTML, '');
document.querySelector('#b').innerHTML = new_order;
```

```css
#a{
  background-color: gold;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}

#b{
  background-color: orange;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.x{
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
 position: relative;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id='a'>
  <div id='b'>
    
    <div class='x'>
      <h1>A</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->
    <div class='x'>
      <h1>B</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->

    <div class='x'>
      <h1>C</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->

    <div class='x'>
      <h1>D</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->
    
  </div><!--</b>-->
</div><!--</a>-->
```

You can even simplify this js into a one-liner if you use `.reduceRight()` instead:

```
document.querySelector('#b').innerHTML = [...document.querySelectorAll('.x')].reduceRight((a, e) => a+e.outerHTML, '');
```

Comment: Thanks Nick Parsons for your reply the reverse ordering works great but how can I set the scroll box to be set at the bottom on page load?

Comment: @fsofb so you wan't the scroll box to be at the bottom of the page? This is difficult to do without css... is adding css via javascript an option?

Answer (score 0):

I have provided a link in the comments and here to a previous similar question with a number of valid answers:
[Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942733/reverse-order-of-a-set-of-elements)

For your question specifically, you can add the following pure JavaScript :

```
<script>

window.onload = function(){
reverseEls("b"); // Reorder your divs
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight); // Scroll to the bottom of the page
    }

function reverseEls(elem){
    elem = document.getElementById(elem);
        for (var i=0;i<elem.childNodes.length;i++) {
            elem.insertBefore(elem.childNodes[i], elem.firstChild);
        }
    }

</script>
```

This will reverse your divs as desired and also scroll to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks cmprogram the reverse ordering works great but sadly the scroll box does not set at the bottom on page load any ideas why is that?

Comment: @fsofb Apparently the previous scroll does not work in ALL browsers. I have amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all of the elements with a class of `x` and you can convert it to an Array with `[].slice.call`. You can then set the `#b` element's innerHTML to `''` which removes all elements inside it and reverse the Array of elements with a class `x` and use `forEach` to append each element to the `#b` element.

You can use `elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;` to scroll `elem` to the bottom.

```css
#a{
  background-color: gold;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}

#b{
  background-color: orange;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.x{
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
 position: relative;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id='a'>
  <div id='b'>
    
    <div class='x'>
      <h1>A</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->
    <div class='x'>
      <h1>B</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->

    <div class='x'>
      <h1>C</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->

    <div class='x'>
      <h1>D</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->
    
  </div><!--</b>-->
</div><!--</a>-->
<script>
var container = document.querySelector('#b');
var elems = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.x'));
container.innerHTML = "";
elems.reverse().forEach(function(elem, index){
 container.appendChild(elem);
});
container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
//scroll to bottom of #b div
var body = document.body,
html = document.documentElement;
var docheight = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                   html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
//get height of document cross-browser
window.scrollTo(0, docheight);
//scroll to bottom of document
</script>
```

JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nfwcp960/embedded/result