# How to reverse the flow of element in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I do this

```
<div>
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
</div>
```

What I expected to be the results

C

B

A

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use flex box. set `flex-direction: column-reverse;`

Comment: CSS Dupe: [How can I reorder my divs using only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220273/how-can-i-reorder-my-divs-using-only-css); A possible JavaScript Dupe: [Reverse order of a set of HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942733/reverse-order-of-a-set-of-html-elements)

Comment: You can also use transform: `div, p {
  transform:scale(-1);
}`  result live : https://jsfiddle.net/hy709jv8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use flexbox :
```

```css
.wrapper{
display :flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using CSS

You can [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items) the items in reverse, by specifying `flex` display.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could transform the child elements by flipping them across their directional axis. Flip the entire `div` and then flip each `p` inside the div. Although this works, it should be avoided in favor of `flex`. **Note:** After transforming the elements, selection will become very wonky.

```css
div, p {
  transform: scale(1, -1);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
</div>
```

---

### Using JavaScript

You could also do this in JavaScript using a function that iterates though a Node's `childNodes` and inserts them before the first child.

```js
/**
 * @describe Reverses the child nodes of a node in-place.
 * @param {Node} node - The parent of the child nodes to be reversed
 */
const reverseChildNodes = node => {
  for (let i = 1; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
    node.insertBefore(node.childNodes[i], node.firstChild);
  }
}

if (Element.prototype.reverseChildren === undefined) {
  Element.prototype.reverseChildren = function() {
    reverseChildNodes(this);
  };
}

// Global function
reverseChildNodes(document.querySelector('.section:first-child'));

// Prototype method on Node object
[...document.querySelectorAll('.section')].pop().reverseChildren();
```

```css
.section { border: thin solid grey; margin: 0.25em; padding: 0.25em; }
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
</div>

<div class="section">
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thanks. I slightly modified it to not flip across the x-axis.